# Partials in sub folders - handlebars (Fabricator)

Tags: handlebars.js, partial, fabricator

I am using fabricator

https://fbrctr.github.io

I have a partial I am trying to include in a template

ones on the top level are fine

```
 {{> standardbutton }}
```

Nested one do not display

```
 {{> buttons/standardbutton }}
```

I could put them all on the top level but it would be nice to group them. Is this possible

Answer (score 3):

After trying every possibility it uses the standard '/' notation.

```
 {{> buttons/standardbutton }}
```